# Angular5 & Material-Dialog - update Dialog-Content asynchronously

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-material, dialog

so I got it finally managed to open a material-dialog and pass data to it (a text with some vars). But now I realized, that I have to update the data in the dialog asynchronously, because the vars change over time, and when the dialog is open, its content needs to be updated.

in my dialog-component I have a:

```
<div class="statusMsg" [innerHTML]="data.messages"></div>
```

I have no idea how to do this. I tried with `| async` but with no effort. Is it generally possible?

Comment: This doesn't work. You send data to teh dialog when you open it. The only way to achieve this is by putting the same http call in the dialog component.

Comment: I still have a similar issue with the material dialog component and one thing I found so far is the solution in "Update 2" on my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215411/angular-material-dialog-how-to-update-the-injected-data-when-they-change-in-the